# Channel.Security.Error accessing flex using IPV6

Tags: apache-flex, exception

I have been encountered with following error accessing flex application(Flex 3.0 and AS/3.0) using IPV6 url. This issue is replicable while accessing using GET requests.

```
"Fault Code: Channel.Security.Error
Fault Detail:Destination: DefaultHTTP
Fault String: Security error accessing url "
```

There is no issue when application is accessed using IPV4.

Investigation so far:

1. Browsers are configured for IPV6, application is accessible using
   IPV6 IP address.  Requests with GET method throw this exception.
2. crossdomain.xml is configured with full access configuration:

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0"?>
>         <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
>         <cross-domain-policy>
>                 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
>                 <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
>                 <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
>         </cross-domain-policy>
> ```

1. crossdomain.xml is located at following server root.  Both client
   side code and server side code reside in the same machine.
   crossdomain.xml is accessible while accessed using http://[IPV6
   IP]:port/crossdomain.xml
2. The flash player used in Firefox and IE is 10.* and above. The
   security configuration that is required in crossdomain.xml for flash
   player 10 and above is already configured.
3. The `<use-network>` flag has been set to "true" during flex
   compilation.

Are there any additional settings that needs to be done to access flex based applications using IPV6?  Any help in this regard would be of great help.

Thanks and Regards,
Raj

Comment: Have you tried to sniff the packet using a tool like ServiceCapture of the Flash Builder Network Monitor?

Comment: It's not clear what the failure symptom is: Does the SWF fail to be loaded? Or does the browser load and run the SWF, but HTTP requests made by the SWF fail? Have tried you compiled the app w/out RSL's?

Comment: Hi, I have tried debug the requests using Firebug and Charles Web debugging proxy, what I have noticed is, the requests that leads to above exception is not captured by these tools. My guess is the security error is thrown as soon as request is made from flex application.                                                      Sunil, SWF is loaded fine through IPV6, it is the http requests that are leading to this exception.